# Does convergence in mean imply convergence in mutual information?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, information-theory

Suppose $X_n (n \leq 1)$ and $Y_n (n \leq 1)$ be two sequences of random variables, if $X_n \rightarrow X$ and $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ in mean, does it imply that $I(X_n,Y_n)\rightarrow I(X,Y)$?

By $I(X, Y)$, I mean mutual information of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: You could simplify the problem and fix $Y_n =Y$, and see what you get.

Comment: @DanielAdams, how can prove in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Consider for a random variable $A$ having finite mean, $X_n = A/n$, $Y_n = A/n$. Then $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converge in mean to zero, but $I(X_n,Y_n) = I(A,A) \nrightarrow I(0,0)$.